# How to find the total average of filtered values in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code allows me the sum per filter key. How do I sum and average all the values together. i.e combine the results of all filtered values.

```
val f= p.groupBy(d => (d.Id))
                      .mapValues(totavg =>           
                      (totavg.groupBy(_.Day).filterKeys(Set(2,3,4)).mapValues(_.map(_.Amount))
```

Sample output:

```
Map(A9 -> Map(2 -> List(473.3, 676.48), 4 -> List(685.45, 812.73))
```

I would like to add all values together and compute total average.
i.e (473.3+676.48+685.45+812.73)/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given `Map`, you can apply `flatMap` twice to return the sequence of values firstly, then calculate the average:

```
val m = Map("A9" -> Map(2 -> List(473.3, 676.48), 4 -> List(685.45, 812.73)))

val s = m.flatMap(_._2.flatMap(_._2))
// s: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Double] = List(473.3, 676.48, 685.45, 812.73)

s.sum/s.size
// res14: Double = 661.99
```